# Kotlin not rendering button correctly in custom adapter layout

Tags: android, kotlin

When using a custom adapter and layout for my listview, the button is not rendering correctly or is not binding inside the getView method:

[image: List View]

code:

```
  override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: 
ViewGroup): View? {
        var convertView = convertView
        val rowView = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.damageitem_row, parent, 
false)
        if (rowView != null) {
            DamageItemHeader = 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.DamageItemHeader)
            DamageItemDetails = 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.DamageItemDetails)
      //  DeleteButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteDIButton) as Button
      //  EditButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.editDIButton) as Button
    }

    DamageItemHeader.text = arrayList[position].RoomTypeInfo!!.RoomName + "/" + arrayList[position].RoomTypeInfo!!.ItemName
    DamageItemDetails.text = arrayList[position].EstCost.toString() + " | " + arrayList[position].Notes





    return rowView
}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/headerDIComponent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DamageItemHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DamageItemDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="25dp">

        <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#d63031"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Delete Me"
            android:textSize="20sp"></Button>

        <View

            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
```

```
<View

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#b2bec3" />
```